# Domain change broke Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps

I recently changed my domain name, therefore the map is not loading where I want it to. It is coming up with the URL error.

However it was a long time ago that the account was made and i cant seem to remember which account I made the key in. However i do have the actual key in Heroku.

Is it any way possible to find out which account the key was made in, by contacting Google and them maybe using the key to find out?

I know this is a long shot.

> Your site URL to be authorized:
>
> Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may request it through a support case via https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support in order to open personalized communication channel with the technical support team for Google Maps API